# comparison of Time with Informations::ActiveRecord_Relation failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
start_datetime = Informations.select("start_datetime")
end_datetime = Informations.select("end_datetime")
now_datetime = Time.now
@information = now_datetime.between?(start_datetime, end_datetime)
```

コントローラーで上記のような指定した時間範囲内の間かどうか判断しその結果をインスタンス変数にもたせようとしたところ下記のようなエラーがでてしまい困っています。

[image]

.between?の引数がいけないのでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Informations`はモデルっぽく見えるのでその前提で回答すると、

> ```
> start_datetime = Informations.select("start_datetime")
> ```

このコードで`start_datetime`に入っているのは`SELECT informations.start_datetime FROM informations`の結果の配列(のようなもの)、つまりinformationsテーブルに入ってるすべてのレコードのstart_datetimeカラムの一覧です

やりたいことをエスパーすると、特定のレコードの`start_datetime`と`end_datetime`と`Time.now`の比較なんじゃないでしょうか。

```
infomation = Informations.find(...)
now_datetime = Time.now
@information = now_datetime.between?(infomation.start_datetime, infomation.end_datetime)
```

Comment: 解決いたしました！詳しいご解説ありがとうございます。別件なのですが「rails g model model名（単数形）」とした場合にクリエイトされる、マイグレーションファイルが単数形になってしまうのですが、問題ないのでしょうか？本来なら複数形のマイグレーションファイルがクリエイトされるはずという認識なのでが。。

Comment: @paisly  問題が解決したのであれば、回答の横に表示されているであろうチェックマークにチェックを入れて回答を「承認」してください。(参考 [回答が「承認された」とはどういう意味ですか?](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)) これをしないといつまでも未回答のまま残ってしまいます。また、別の質問があるならそれは新たに質問として投稿してください。